# How do I make sure a string contains one element and also doesn't contain another? // How do I check a file's type?

Tags: c++, string, find

I have a file path `fileLocation`(coming from a `std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator`) and am trying to determine if it's of type ".png".
I am expecting file directories, png files, and mcmeta files, which contain the line `.png` in their name.

in other words, I need an if statement that will separate `C:\files\file.png` from `C:\files` and `C:\files\file.png.mcmeta`

I tried

```cpp
if (fileLocation.path().string().find(".png") == fileLocation.path().string().size()-4) {/*...*/}
```

but for some reason it only returned a false value in the file that came *after* the file which wasn't a png.

Comment: Maybe you want to look at the extension itself: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/extension](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/extension)

Comment: You can use `std::string::length()`  or `std::string::size` to check if the string contains one element.

Comment: You really can't check a file's type unless you have some kind of identifier inside the file.  In many operating systems, the name does not have to relate to a file's type or purpose.  Take the infamous extension ".dat" for example.  I could also have an executable with the extension ".txt".  Also, example ".h" -- you don't know if it is a C++ header or a C language header.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews this worked. I suggest you pot this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like the following for more complicated searches based on file naming conventions:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::string input_dir{"/home/user/Pictures/"};
  std::vector<std::string> pngs;
  for(auto& f : fs::directory_iterator(input_dir)) {
    auto fn = f.path().filename().string();
    auto ext = fn.substr(fn.rfind("."), fn.size()-1);
    if(ext.find(".png") != std::string::npos)
      pngs.push_back(fn);
    else
      std::cout << fn << " is not a png.\n";
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```